# Создание корректного std::regex приводит к синтаксической ошибке

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

### Проблема

Создание объекта `std::regex` приводит к синтаксическому исключению, однако ни я, ни онлайн сервисы не видят в инициализируемом выражении синтаксической ошибки.

### Пример

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        regex R("^([^;]+);(?:\\s*([^=]+)=((?<q>\"?)([^\"]*)\\k<q>);?)*$", regex_constants::ECMAScript);
    }
    catch (const regex_error& e) {
        cout << "regex_error caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
        if (e.code() == regex_constants::error_brack) {
            cout << "The code was error_brack\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Вывод

```
regex_error caught: regex_error(error_syntax)
```

### Примечания

- Без экранизации: `^([^;]+);(?:\s*([^=]+)=((?<q>"?)([^"]*)\k<q>);?)*$`
- На [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4txvhQ/2)

### Вопросы

- В чем причина возникновения этой проблемы?
- Если таки синтаксическая ошибка, то может вы знаете сервисы, помогающие находить таковые каверзы?

Comment: по всей видимости, плюсовая реализация не поддерживает именнованные группы...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поддержка именнованных захватывающих групп в `std::regex` не реализована. Необходимо заменить их на нумерованные захватывающие группы.

Также, удобнее задавать регулярные выражения с помощью "сырых" строковых литералов, чтобы использовать только один символ обратной косой черты.

Объявление вашего выражения можно записать как

```cpp
regex R(R"(^([^;]+);(?:\s*([^=]+)=((\"?)([^\"]*)\4);?)*$)");
```

Группа "q" заменена группой №4. `R"(...)"` — функциональная часть строкового литерала, сам шаблон находится внутри скобок.

См. [пример работы кода на C++](https://ideone.com/kunuYx):

```cpp
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    try {
        regex R(R"(^([^;]+);(?:\s*([^=]+)=((\"?)([^\"]*)\4);?)*$)");
        string s("attached; filename=\"Hello, world!.docx\"");
        smatch m;
        if (regex_search(s, m, R)) {
            std::cout << m[0] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch (const regex_error& e) {
        cout << "regex_error caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
        if (e.code() == regex_constants::error_brack) {
            cout << "The code was error_brack\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```